# FileInputStream prevents external writing operations?

Tags: java, windows, file-locking

Running the following code and editing the file using WordPad triggers a "***The document is in use by another application and cannot be accessed***" error.

Windows seems to lock the file for writing operations even if an input stream is used. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

        while (true) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

My Java app is reading a file controlled by an external application on which I have no control. Reading the file interferes with the external application.

Comment: That's as expected - you wouldn't want to be busy reading a file and then have someone change it underneath you.  You can certainly override the default sharing mode from native code, but I have no idea whether there is any way to do it in Java; you might have to shell out to an external application to do it for you.  `cmd /c type filename.txt` should do the trick.

Comment: "you wouldn't want to be busy reading a file and then have someone change it underneath you." why not? It's easy to cope with that kind of changes, specially if data are appended at the end of the file. I guess opening a file for read/write operations should protect the file from external alterations. But I don't see why the file should be locked for read-only operations.

Comment: If you're reading data from the file and the content you're reading changes as you are reading it you may get part of the old content and part of the new content, and there's no way to tell which is which.  Even if the other process is only appending to the file, you'll still have problems unless you have some way of working out whether a particular block of data is complete yet or not.  All of these are solvable if the two processes are co-operating, but Java has no way to tell whether that's true or not.